# как отключить адаптивность bootstrap на мониторе?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Возможно ли как то отключить адаптацию к экрану если человек увеличивает (zoom'ит) сайт в браузере? Изначально он подстраивается под ширину экрана. Конечно можно было бы попыхтеть что бы он идеально смотрелся на всех экранах, но сайт слишком перенасыщен колонками. В общем нужно что бы если человек увеличивает в процентах zoom то сайт увеличивался целиком как обычный сайт с фиксированной шириной. Что бы увеличивалось просто пропорционально все, будто он не адаптивный. Как stackoverflow когда его зумишь на компьютере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Официальная документация](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

> Disabling responsiveness
>
> Bootstrap automatically adapts your pages for various screen sizes. Here's how to disable this feature so your page works like this non-responsive example.
>
> Steps to disable page responsiveness:
>   1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
>   2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
>   3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
>   4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

1. Убрать тег:

   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
2. Переопределить класс, можно без !important, придется поиграться со специфичностью..

   `.container { width: 970px !important; }`
3. Если используется navbar (меню) то требуется удалить классы для поведения "collapse". (В данном случае видимо это лишнее)
4. Классы колонок, col-lg-*, col-md-*, col-sm-*, заменить на .col-xs-*

Answer (score 3):

Это русский stackowerflow, так что вот конкретное решение:

1) Нужно убрать мета-тэг:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

2) Необходимо поменять ширину класса `.container` 
    Это можно сделать следующим образом

```
.container{
    width:960px !important;
}
```

3) Везде в сетке используйте класс `.col-xs-`

---

**P.S.** Важный момент заданный стиль должен затирать родной стиль bootsrap. Удачного кодинга...